# Çinlar's Probability and Stochastic, Examples 2.11 and 2.12

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, laplace-transform, gamma-function

I have two questions about a few steps in Çinlar's derivations of Examples 2.11 and 2.12.

1. (Blue highlight) How did he go from $\mathbb{E}f(X+Y, \frac{X}{X+Y})$ to $\int_{0}^{\infty}dx\frac{x^{a-1}e^{-x}}{\Gamma(a)}\int_{0}^{\infty}dy\frac{x^{b-1}e^{-y}}{\Gamma(b)}f(x+y, \frac{x}{x+y})$? I can understand that from Theorem 2.4, we have $\mathbb{E}f\circ X = \mu f$, so the integral will look something like $\int_{0}^{\infty}\mu(dx)\int_{0}^{1}K(x,dy)f(x,y)$, but where did the transitional kernel go in his derivation?
2. (Green highlight) He said that $\mathbb{P}\{R > r\} = (\frac{c}{c+r})^a$ according to the Laplace transform computation above in 2.11, but I don't really get it... What does this have anything to do with 2.11 (the previous example)? It doesn't seem like the previous example has anything to do with the Laplace transform.

Thanks to everyone in advance for helping out!

Here are the screenshots of the above examples and Theorem 2.4:

Example 2.11:
[image: Example 2.11]

Example 2.12:
[image]
[image]

Theorem 2.4:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The blue highlight is just using the fact that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent with respective densities $f_X(x),f_Y(y),$ then by [LOTUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician),

$$E[g(X,Y)]=\int_\mathbb{R_+}\int_\mathbb{R_+}g(x,y)f_X(x)f_Y(y)dydx\\
=\int_\mathbb{R_+}f_X(x)\int_\mathbb{R_+}g(x,y)f_Y(y)dydx.$$

Yours is the case where $g(X,Y)=f(X+Y,\frac{X}{X+Y})$ for a positive Borel function $f$ on $\mathbb{R_+}\times [0,1],$ and $f_X,f_Y$ are standard gamma densities.

2. As for the green highlight, not sure exactly how the author meant to tie it into Example 2.11 (is there an *equation* also labelled 2.11?). I guess one way to tie it in is by using $f(u,v)=e^{-ruv}$ since the integral in Example 2.11 would then be computing $E[e^{-rX}]$ as desired (at least for standard gamma $X$). But you can also get their result by using the MGF of a gamma random variable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! For part 1, I understood the properties you said. What I was confused about is that, isn't $X + Y$ ⫫ $\frac{X}{X+Y}$ the claim we're trying to prove? How can we just plug it in as a known fact and assume product measure? For part 2, I guess it could be a typo from the author as I don't see any other equation called 2.11...

Comment: It uses independence of $X$ and $Y$, not independence of $X+Y$ and $X/(X+Y)$, no?

Comment: Alright, I think I got it! Thanks. For part 2, I am kind of certain that it is a typo. It should be using the calculation in example 2.10 instead of 2.11, and using that I'm able to get the presented result.

Comment: Ah, okay great!